# arrays to store 20 numbers, then display the highest, lowest, total of the numbers and the average

Tags: arrays, algorithm

How do I write an array that stores 20 numbers and then displays the following data: the lowest number in the array, the highest, the total of the numbers and the average of them?

Comment: Consider adding more detail to your question in order to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using java programing language

```
int myArray[] = {15,25,85,32,74,15,3,25,63,32,2,1,9,4,54,25,0,65,74};

int max = myArray[0];
int min = myArray[0];
int sum = 0;

for (int i=0 ; i< myArray.length() ; i++){
    if(myArray[i] > max){
        max=myArray[i];
    }

    if(myArray[i] < min){
        min=myArray[i]; 
    }

    sum += myArray[i];
}
int average = sum / myArray.length();
```

Comment: I would have suggested providing pseudocode instead of a specific implementation.